# Nox emulator with React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm setting up my development environment for React Native with a custom Android Emulator (Nox).

I followed the steps on this website:
[How to connect Android Studio with Nox App Player](https://www.bignox.com/blog/how-to-connect-android-studio-with-nox-app-player-for-android-development-and-debug/)

But when I type: `adb devices` it still shows nothing.

So when I try to run my app with `react-native run-android` it says that there is no Android simulator running.

Is there something I missed or someone with the same problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Open terminal and type `adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001`. type `adb devices` to make sure your emulator is connected.
2. Go to your project, type `react-native run-android --deviceId 127.0.0.1:62001`, waiting for the project to finish compiling, and the you will see a red error screen.
3. Open the `developer menu`, Go to `Dev Settings → Debug server host for device`, Assume your local ip is `192.168.1.121`, then type: `192.168.1.121:8081`
4. Use `developer menu` to reload your app,then close the app, and reopen it.

Comment: Thanks! The app now shows up in the emulator. But now I get the following error: Could not run adb reverse: Command failed: adb -s 127.0.0.1:62001 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081. This shuts down the server so it's still not working.

Comment: i got this after run command `react-native run-android --deviceId=127.0.0.1:62001`
this error`Running adb -s 127.0.0.1:62001 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
error: closed
Could not run adb reverse: Command failed: adb -s 127.0.0.1:62001 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Installing the app on the device (cd android && adb -s 127.0.0.1:62001 install app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
Invalid APK file: app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
Command failed: adb -s 127.0.0.1:62001 install app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk`

Comment: Where can i find Dev Settings?

Comment: @ufxmeng Where can I find the Dev Settings?

Comment: to find Dev Settings you must activate developer mode.... click 5 times on compile number

Comment: ctrl+0 or `shake` will bring up Dev settings

Comment: On Mac, it seems there's no shake feature. I have to go to Nox installation directory  to find `adb` command in `/Applications/Nox App Player.app/Contents/MacOS`. Then exec `adb shell input keyevent 82` to open the developer menu.

Comment: `error No Android devices connected`  when i run `react-native run-android --deviceId 127.0.0.1:62001`

Comment: for adding more information, after adding nox' path to the environment variables, my problem got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Open terminal and type `adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001`. type `adb devices`
>    to make sure your emulator is connected.
> 2. Go to your project, type `react-native run-android --deviceId 127.0.0.1:62001`, waiting for the project to finish compiling, and then you will see a red error screen.
> 3. Open the developer menu, Go to Dev Settings → Debug server host for device, Assume your local ip is 192.168.1.121, then type:
>    `192.168.1.121:8081`
> 4. Use developer menu to reload your app,then close the app, and reopen it.

Just in step 2 type `react-native run-android` (if you don't work with android >10 add prefix) `--no-jetifier`. It works for me!

Answer (score 0):

it mean **for android v 4.1.1 in nox emulator adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001**
**for android v 5.1.1 in nox emulator adb connect 127.0.0.1:62025**

Comment: Hi Roman, can you fix the formatting on this answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
adb connect localhost:62001
react-native run-android --deviceId localhost:62001
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open NoxPlayer Emulator > Go to Settings > General > Startup items > Check Root
2. Enable debugging mode/options and USB debugging
3. Run `adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001`
4. Run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`
5. Run `npm run android`
6. Press d to open the developer menu
7. Go to settings > Debug server host & port for devices
8. Input the <YOUR_DEVICE_IP_NUMBER>:8081

If you are not able to open the dev menu run the step 4 command again.