# ADB can't connect to Nox

Tags: android, react-native, adb

i have a problem which i trying to solve for about 3 days and i can't find any working solution. The problem is i can't connect my nox player to adb when i trying to connect with localhost and port 62001.  Everything i did is:

-nox_adb.exe

> nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62001 -> unable to connect to
> 127.0.0.1:62001.
>
> nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:5037 -> connected to 127.0.0.1:5037 (but
> when i trying to run react native project with this deviceId, it
> returns "No Android devices connected")

-adb.exe (from Android SDK)

> adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62001 -> unable to connect to
> 127.0.0.1:62001.
>
> adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:5037 -> failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:5037.

I have installed whole android studio with (i think) needed libraries, Google USB Driver, sdk platforms, etc.
Platform: Windows 7 x64
Nox: 6.2.0.0

i have read:

- https://forum.xda-developers.com/tools/android-studio/how-to-connect-android-studio-nox-app-t3241330 - connected succesfully but when starting project, react did'nt see any devices
- https://www.bignox.com/blog/how-to-connect-android-studio-with-nox-app-player-for-android-development-and-debug/ - can't connect
- [Nox emulator with React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46235080/nox-emulator-with-react-native) - cant connect
- [Nox App Player not connect with Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40004779/nox-app-player-not-connect-with-android-studio) - can't connect to ---:62001, react didn't see device when connected

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Of course, Nox 6.2.0.0 from https://www.bignox.com/

Comment: Anyone, anything?\

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Okay, after couple hours i've got the cause of the problem.

I was trying to reinstall whole Android Studio with SDK Tools, NOX player, clear cache of this apps and results was the same, can't connect to device... I couldn't find any information about to how change NOX player IP/Port or where to get my Nox player IP/Port (on every site was the same information - nox connect with 127.0.0.1:62001), so I came up with an idea to check listening ports on my computer.

At first i was type in command line "**netstat -aon | find '62001'**" to find application, that listening on port 62001. In result none application has listening on this port... okay, sounds good.

In next step i checked all running application with command "**tasklist**" to find Nox running tasks and their PID... and i have found:

**(I had running Nox Emulator while doing this steps)**

- Nox.exe
- NoxVMSVC.exe
- NoxVMHandle.exe

Then i checked every process with command "**netstat -aon | findstr PID**" (PID is process ID, which you will got after typed command "**tasklist**")

In **Nox.exe** none port is correct, every time 'cannot connect...'

In **NoxVMSVC.exe** none port is listening (empty list)

In **NoxVMHandle.exe** i had about seven ports that is listening... so i checked one by one and i have found the correct port (**62025**) for connecting to device

So finally i can to connect to Nox Emulator without any problem, with command "adb connect 127.0.0.1:62025". Emulator working fine with React-Native project, application has installed correctly.

Maybe someone will have similar problem with connect to Nox Emulator.

Best Wishes!

Comment: thank you very much, was needing the same and you saved me a couple of hours!

Comment: Finally you saved me! It was exactly what I was looking for. I could solve my issue by typing adb connect 127.0.0.1:62025 in CMD inside the (dir to nox)\Nox\bin dir. Thank you so much

Answer (score 23):

This [ref](https://www.bignox.com/blog/how-to-connect-android-studio-with-nox-app-player-for-android-development-and-debug/) should resolve your problem, here is the summary:

1. Enable "Root" checkbox in nox setting
2. Go to setting in nox emulator, turn on developer option, turn on usb debugging
3. Go to nox directory, run command: nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62001 
   It works for me :D

Answer (score 17):

This worked for me. (for windows)

1. Goto adb folder

```
C:\Users\YOUR_NAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
```

2. Open command here, and run

```
adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001
```

Like this

```
C:\Users\YOUR_NAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001
```

Answer (score 3):

Run this in cmd.exe.

```
for /f "tokens=2" %a in ('tasklist ^|findstr Nox.') do  netstat -aon | findstr %a
```

It will print out something like this.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Bignox\BigNoxVM\RT>for /f "tokens=2" %a in ('tasklist ^|findstr Nox.') do  netstat -aon | findstr %a

C:\Program Files (x86)\Bignox\BigNoxVM\RT>netstat -aon   | findstr 15260
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1209         127.0.0.1:58001        ESTABLISHED     15260
  TCP    127.0.0.1:26966        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       15260
  UDP    0.0.0.0:64800          *:*                                    15260
  UDP    0.0.0.0:64801          *:*                                    15260

C:\Program Files (x86)\Bignox\BigNoxVM\RT>netstat -aon   | findstr 11180

C:\Program Files (x86)\Bignox\BigNoxVM\RT>netstat -aon   | findstr 16120
  TCP    127.0.0.1:52001        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       16120
  TCP    127.0.0.1:52001        127.0.0.1:1987         ESTABLISHED     16120
  TCP    127.0.0.1:53001        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       16120
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57001        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       16120
  TCP    127.0.0.1:58001        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       16120
  TCP    127.0.0.1:58001        127.0.0.1:1209         ESTABLISHED     16120
  TCP    127.0.0.1:58001        127.0.0.1:1975         ESTABLISHED     16120
  TCP    127.0.0.1:60001        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       16120
  TCP    127.0.0.1:61001        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       16120
  TCP    127.0.0.1:64001        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       16120
  TCP    192.168.1.133:1245     157.240.14.32:443      ESTABLISHED     16120
  TCP    192.168.1.133:1248     172.217.2.195:443      CLOSE_WAIT      16120
  TCP    192.168.1.133:1267     108.177.12.188:5228    ESTABLISHED     16120
  TCP    192.168.1.133:1271     172.217.2.138:443      CLOSE_WAIT      16120
  TCP    192.168.1.133:1274     172.217.2.74:443       CLOSE_WAIT      16120
  TCP    192.168.1.133:1275     172.217.8.98:443       CLOSE_WAIT      16120
  TCP    192.168.1.133:1278     172.217.2.138:443      CLOSE_WAIT      16120
  TCP    192.168.1.133:1280     172.217.2.74:443       CLOSE_WAIT      16120
  TCP    192.168.1.133:1282     172.217.2.74:443       CLOSE_WAIT      16120
  TCP    192.168.1.133:1300     149.154.175.55:5222    ESTABLISHED     16120
  TCP    192.168.1.133:1301     172.217.8.78:443       CLOSE_WAIT      16120
  TCP    192.168.1.133:1329     172.217.3.78:80        CLOSE_WAIT      16120
  TCP    192.168.1.133:1436     172.217.2.138:443      CLOSE_WAIT      16120
  TCP    192.168.1.133:1437     172.217.8.74:443       CLOSE_WAIT      16120
  TCP    192.168.1.133:1439     172.217.8.74:443       CLOSE_WAIT      16120
  TCP    192.168.1.133:1967     172.217.3.74:443       ESTABLISHED     16120
  UDP    0.0.0.0:51197          *:*                                    16120
  UDP    0.0.0.0:51198          *:*                                    16120
  UDP    0.0.0.0:54730          *:*                                    16120
  UDP    0.0.0.0:62578          *:*                                    16120
  UDP    127.0.0.1:59001        *:*                                    16120
  UDP    127.0.0.1:65001        *:*                                    16120
```

The 3rd column is your port.

Also make sure to turn OFF USB debugging.  This uses something different.

The basic idea of the script here is to find all processes named Nox.exe.  get their PID, then find any ports attached to the Nox.exe processes.

you will now connect with the following:

```
"c:\Program Files\Nox\bin\adb.exe" connect 127.0.0.1:52001
"c:\Program Files\Nox\bin\adb.exe" -s 127.0.0.1:52001 shell
```

Answer (score 3):

with the help of @Faramarz Bayat and @Mateusz

- go to Nox bin folder
- open file `base.vbox` with text editor (this is an xml file)
- go to line `<Forwarding name . . .`

you will find the ports list

- your port number is the `hostport` where `guestport=5555`
- therefore connect the device using `adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001` (62001 is
  my port#)

Answer (score 2):

According to @infi's answer cd-ing into platform-tools helped me on Windows. But I needed a command I could call easily every time I need it. So I opened `_adb.cmd` on a directory I had already have on my environment variable path.

```
@echo off
cmd /c "cd %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools & adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001"
```

So anytime I call the command `_adb`, it does the job for me.

You can simply run

```
cd %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools & adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001
```

on your terminal if you need it once.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but it seems to be still a problem for many fellow developers.

The thing that fixed the problem for me was to add a PATH entry to environment variables with the path of Nox's bin folder. Just notice that this path entry must be above the Android SDK's platform tools' path entry.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that worked for me:

You need to open folder where you have your Nox installed and open `bin` folder, then delete `adb.exe` and `nox_adb.exe`.
Then, go to `AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`, copy two times `adb.exe` file: one with it's original name and second named `nox_adb.exe` and paste it to Nox folder.

Summarizing:

- download [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platform-tools),
- go to Android SDK folder,
- make two copies of `adb.exe` -> `adb.exe` and `nox_adb.exe`
- paste it into `\Nox\bin`

Answer (score 0):

go to user name of user in pc and than app data and local android sdk and copy two file under adb and than past it on program file nox bin and replace it and that is it

Answer (score 0):

Alright here is a dumb-down solution for newbies like me 'who are using nox player and not android studio':

In order to run adb command in nox. In windows open the nox folder where all the files are
installed in that go to **bin**

then open a command prompt there

type in `adb devices`

if you face an error like this: `List of devices attached

- daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
- daemon started successfully *

D:\apps\Nox\bin>adb devices
List of devices attached
//empty port and ip here
`

then that means you didnt open nox player in the background. so go do that first
and now rerun the command in cmd and voila!

other useful commands include "adb connect " and

lastly then type `adb shell` to start working there