# Android Studio Flamingo Debug Console not working

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, remote-debugging

Recently I updated my Android Studio to Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2.1. Also, in some projects, I upgrade AGP dependency from 7.4.2 to 8.0.0.

From that point, I am not able to use Debug-Console. The Console screen is showing only "Open Logcat..." and "Connected..." as the image below shows. I did some tests on Physical and Virtual devices with the same result.

I think the problem is not related to the upgrade AGP dependency from 7.4.2 to 8.0.0 because some projects using the previous version 7.4.2 and the Debug-Console has exactly the same issue.

[image: Debug Console]

Comment: **According to Issue Tracker, this is a Bug.**


[Issue #37137285](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/fixed-bugs/studio/2022.2.1)



[Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37137285)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Flamingo on M1 Mac and I'm also facing debugging issue, but different from yours. My gradle version is 7.3.3. I have no problem debugging on emulators and some of my physical devices, but some other physical devices do not work. Debug will launch, but brake points will never be reached. Super weird. Reverted back to Electrical Eel and problem fixed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `@Qikai` There is a solution for your problem, just go to `gradle.properties` file and change `android.nonTransitiveRClass=false` to `android.nonTransitiveRClass=true` and `android.enableR8.fullMode=true` to `android.enableR8.fullMode=false` then sync and debug the project. Now your break points will work.

Answer (score 1):

**The Full solution:**

As [Qikai Gao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9390955/qikai-gao) suggests download the [Android Studio Electric Eel 2022_1_1 Patch 2](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive).

However, if you already upgrade AGP dependency from 7.4.2 to 8.0.0 you have to revert the version to 7.4.2 otherwise you end up with multiple errors.

**Revert AGP to 7.4.2**

*1,  build.gradle*

```
    dependencies {
//      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
```

*2, gradle.properties*

```
#android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true
#android.nonTransitiveRClass=false
#android.nonFinalResIds=false
```

*3, Gradle.wrapper-properties (Mac)*

```
#distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
```

Comment: any fixes other than downgrading?

Answer (score 1):

You can be forgiven for being confused or thinking there's a bug or configuration issue, since this wasn't communicated to the community in release notes or other typical channels, but there was an intentional decision to remove the debug console's functionality in Flamingo.

See: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37137285

In the comments there, Android Studio developers say that Logcat is the intended way to view debug logs now.

To preserve the convenience of the old debug consoles behavior, in `edit run/debug configurations` Logcat can be set to open automatically at app launch.  In the logcat filter box, use `package:mine` to view only logs from your app.

Answer (score 0):

try clicking on the emulator link to go to Logcat or click on Logcat

[image].

Comment: Unfortunately, when you filter your log in the Logcat you can't read or catch Exceptions. However, if you have the Debug fully working then you can filter something in the Logcat and at the same time you can read Exception or create another filter for your log.

Answer (score 0):

Installing NDK fixed it for me.  I tracked it down to the Debugger setting of Detect Automatically for Debug Type being the issue.  If I set it to Java Only, it worked fine.  So the detection must be selecting Dual (Java + Native).  I installed NDK 25.2.9519653 and it is now working.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solutions listed above, but none of them worked. Then I tried the "Invalidate Caches" option, which worked for me. The steps are as follows:

1. In Android Studio go to File->Invalidate Caches...
2. Invalidate Caches window will open, select which caches you want to clear
3. Click "Invalidate and Restart" button.

This will clear caches and restart the Android Studio.

Later I found below in IntelliJ IDEA site clicking the help button of Invalidate Caches window:

> When you invalidate the cache, IntelliJ IDEA removes the cache files for all projects ever run in the current version of the IDE. The files will be recreated the next time you open these projects. The IDE also rebuilds the projects if they are built with the native IntelliJ IDEA builder.
> Note the following before you proceed:
>
> - The caches will not be deleted until you restart IntelliJ IDEA.
> - Opening and closing a project without invalidating the cache does not result in deleting any cached files.
> - Local History is not deleted when you invalidate the cache unless you explicitly enable this option in the Invalidate Caches dialog. However, mind that Local History has a retention period of 5 working days by default.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (using third-party emulator Nox Player) I was not able to debug my apps and to work with Logcat at the same time under Flamingo.

So, if you are looking for that, the one more solution found without any downgrading.

If you need logging your app just switch to old-styled Logcat by unchecking the flag **Settings->Experimental->Logcat->Enable new Logcat tool window** that is checked by default.

But if you need debuging your app just back to the new-styled Logcat and then open Debug panel by **View->Tool Windows->Debug**

It is strongly inconvenient way but this solved my issue.

If you are using Android Studio Giraffe there is disappeared the switching to old-styled LogCat possibility. So you may look at [ADB can't connect to Nox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51214825/adb-cant-connect-to-nox). I found useful for me of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63154983/2315037) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76632603/2315037) answers.